# How to call a particular object's method and have affect only on that object which is a value of a key of a dictionary in pygame?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, mouse

I am a new learner of programming. I am practiceing python and writing a litle game using pygame. I have ten circle on the pygame window and each have a counter. I want to increase the counter by 1 when it's circle is clicked. I first created group using .sprite.Group(), but I could not get the desired result. Because then the counter does not even get update. So I create two list, one for the circle and one for the counter. And for each circle in the circle list I created a dictionary taking the circle as the key and each counter in the circle list is the value of the circle. Now when the circle got clicked then the all counter gets updated, not the  counter  that the circle holds. But goal is to get the specific counter updated for it's circle.
(hole == circle)

dig_hole.py(This is the main file.)

```
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.sprite import Group

from counter import Counter
from hole import Hole
from settings import Settings

class DigHole:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Dig Hole")
        pygame.display.set_icon(Hole(self).image)

        self.count = Counter(self)
        self.counter_group = list()
        self.holes = list()

        self.dict = dict()

        self._create_holes()
        self.hole = Hole(self)

        self.mouse_pos = (0, 0)

    def run_dig_hole(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_hole_clicked_events(self.mouse_pos)

    def _check_hole_clicked_events(self, mouse_pos):
        for key in self.dict:
            if key.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                self.dict[key].count_clock += 1
                self.dict[key].prep_counter()
                self.count.prep_counter()

    def _create_holes(self):
        for row_number in range(2):
            for hole_number in range(5):
                self._create_hole(row_number, hole_number)

        for hole in self.holes:
            counter = Counter(self)
            counter.counter_rect.midbottom = hole.rect.midtop
            self.counter_group.append(counter)

        for hole in self.holes:
            for counter in self.counter_group:
                self.dict[hole] = counter

        
    def _create_hole(self, row_number, hole_number):
            hole = Hole(self)
            hole_width, hole_height = hole.rect.size
            available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * hole_width)
            available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - (2 * hole_height)
            hole.x =(((available_space_x // 5) - hole_width) // 2) + (available_space_x // 5) * hole_number 
            hole.rect.x = hole.x
            hole.rect.y = 2 * hole.rect.height + (available_space_y - (4 * hole_height)) * row_number
            self.holes.append(hole)

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        for key in self.dict:
            key.draw()
        
        for key in self.dict:
            self.dict[key].counter_rect.midbottom = key.rect.midtop
            self.dict[key].show_counter()

        self.count.show_counter()
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dh = DigHole()
    dh.run_dig_hole()
```

hole.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Hole():
    def __init__(self, dh):
        # super().__init__()
        self.screen = dh.screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/circle.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

counter.py

```
import pygame.font
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Counter():
    def __init__(self, dh):
        # super().__init__()
        self.screen = dh.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = dh.settings

        self.count_clock = 0        

        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        self.prep_counter()

    def prep_counter(self):
        counter_str = str(self.count_clock)
        self.counter_image = self.font.render(counter_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        self.counter_rect = self.counter_image.get_rect()
        self.counter_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.counter_rect.top = 20

    def show_counter(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.counter_image, self.counter_rect)
```

Thank you.[This is the window of the progeam. Here all circles are gets update but one is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGAUL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, in `_create_holes`, you set the counters of each circle to be the same Counter object.

```py
        for hole in self.holes:
            for counter in self.counter_group:
                self.dict[hole] = counter
```

Unrolling the inner loop, this is the same as

```py
        for hole in self.holes:
            self.dict[hole] = self.counter_group[0]
            self.dict[hole] = self.counter_group[1]
            self.dict[hole] = self.counter_group[2]
            ...
            self.dict[hole] = self.counter_group[-1]
```

The first assignments are all immediately overwritten, so this code is setting every `self.dict` value to `self.counter_group[-1]`. What you want to do instead is

```py
        for hole, counter in zip(self.holes, self.counter_group):
            self.dict[hole] = counter
```

which iterates over both `self.holes` and `self.counter_group` simultaneously. In your case, you can actually rewrite this as

```py
        self.dict = dict(zip(self.holes, self.counter_group))
```

which is nicer.

I’m not sure, but I think you intend `self.count` to be a total. If this is the case, it won’t quite work: you’re missing a line from `_check_hole_clicked_events`. It should look like this:

```py
    def _check_hole_clicked_events(self, mouse_pos):
        for key in self.dict:
            if key.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                self.dict[key].count_clock += 1
                self.dict[key].prep_counter()
                self.count.count_clock += 1
                self.count.prep_counter()
```

As a side note, I noticed you also wrote `list()` and `dict()` to create empty lists and dicts. It’s more efficient and idiomatic just to write literals (`[]` and `{}`).

Comment: This is working now thank you @LeopardShark.  Now I understand why the counter only shows up top of the last hole when I used sprite..Group. Yes, the self.count is counting the total clicks.